# Value not updating automatically in angularJS with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, socket.io, mean.io

Following is my `angularJS` code with `socket.io` which is only fetching value when I switch from a view, though I was expecting it to update the value automatically. Let me know what I am doing wrong here -

```
angular.module("app").controller("DashboardController", function($scope, SessionService) {
    $scope.user = SessionService.currentUser;

  // Code for realtime notifications
  if (SessionService.currentUser._id) {
      var socket = io('http://localhost:6868');
          socket.emit('get notifications', {user_id: SessionService.currentUser._id});
      socket.on('notification data', function(data){
          $scope.$apply(function() {
              $scope.notificationCount = data.length;
          });
      });
  }     
});
```

Comment: Let me know if you need any other details

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to do $scope.$apply here. You can assign the new value without this. Socket looks better here as an angularjs factory.

Look into this code to know how to use socket as a factory.

https://github.com/sojharo/Simplest-Mean/blob/master/public/javascripts/MyAngularApp.js

Keep things separate

Comment: You should write io.connect() instead of io(). I wanted you to capture mistake yourself by looking at example code